# ERROR 000358: Invalid expression Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer)

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, error-000358

I have the code below

```py
import arcpy, os 
from arcpy.sa import *    
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fc = r'E:\dada proj\DRAW OBJECTS\VIPPoints.mdb\FINALDATA'
# Point feature class, needs to be in a file geodatabase (for the where clause to work)
output_folder = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata'  # Where the rasters will be saved

date_field = 'datc'  # field holding the dates (date type, not string)
value_fields = ['CO', 'O3', 'NO2']  # field with the values to interpolate

all_dates = list({i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, date_field)})  # List all unique dates
    
for date in all_dates:
    # Create a feature layer of each unique date
    where = "{0}=date '{1}'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=fc, field=date_field),
                                    date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=fc, out_layer='lyr', where_clause=where)

    # For each field interpolate. This is untested since I dont have spatial analyst
    for fieldname in value_fields:
        outIDW = Idw(in_point_features='lyr', z_field=fieldname,
                     cell_size=10)  # , {power}, {search_radius}, {in_barrier_polyline_features})
        outIDW.save(os.path.join(output_folder, '{0}_{1}.tif'.format(fieldname, date.strftime('%Y%m%d'))))
```

For the result I got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.1/scratches/arcgis.py", line 25, in <module>
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=fc, out_layer='lyr', where_clause=where)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 6979, in MakeFeatureLayer
    raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression [datc]=date '2019-11-10'
Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer).
```

But I don't now why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data needs to be in a file geodatabase, not a personal (mdb) for the current where clause to work. This is because different data sources require different where clause syntax, see:

[sql reference for query expressions used in arcgis](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm)

Use Copy Features to convert the mdb to a fgdb. Or modify the where clause line of the code.